# Why does npm-shrinkwrap flip-flops between names and URLs every time?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-shrinkwrap

Using:

node v4.6.2, npm 2.15.5, nvm 0.29.0, Homebrew 1.1.1-64-g17bad9a, macOS 10.12.1

Steps:

- I update `package.json`,
- delete all my modules: `rm -fr node_modules`,
- reinstall everything: `nvm exec npm install`,
- and update the shrinkwrap: `nvm exec npm shrinkwrap --dev`.

Result:

Every time, the `from` field of every module will change between a name and a URL, as pictured in this partial capture of `npm-shrinkwrap.json` diff:

```
diff --git a/npm-shrinkwrap.json b/npm-shrinkwrap.json
index e1f679a..476febe 100644
--- a/npm-shrinkwrap.json
+++ b/npm-shrinkwrap.json
@@ -4,86 +4,86 @@
   "dependencies": {
     "active-model-adapter": {
       "version": "2.1.1",
-      "from": "active-model-adapter@2.1.1",
+      "from": "https://registry.npmjs.org/active-model-adapter/-/active-model-adapter-2.1.1.tgz",
       "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/active-model-adapter/-/active-model-adapter-2.1.1.tgz"
     },
     "bootstrap-daterangepicker": {
       "version": "2.1.21",
-      "from": "bootstrap-daterangepicker@2.1.21",
+      "from": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap-daterangepicker/-/bootstrap-daterangepicker-2.1.21.tgz",
       "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap-daterangepicker/-/bootstrap-daterangepicker-2.1.21.tgz",
       "dependencies": {
         "jquery": {
           "version": "3.1.1",
-          "from": "jquery@>=1.10.0",
+          "from": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery/-/jquery-3.1.1.tgz",
           "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery/-/jquery-3.1.1.tgz"
         }
       }
     },
     "bower": {
       "version": "1.8.0",
-      "from": "bower@1.8.0",
+      "from": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.8.0.tgz",
       "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.8.0.tgz"
     },
     "broccoli-asset-rev": {
       "version": "2.5.0",
-      "from": "broccoli-asset-rev@>=2.2.0 <3.0.0",
+      "from": "https://registry.npmjs.org/broccoli-asset-rev/-/broccoli-asset-rev-2.5.0.tgz",
       "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/broccoli-asset-rev/-/broccoli-asset-rev-2.5.0.tgz",
       "dependencies": {
         "broccoli-asset-rewrite": {
           "version": "1.1.0",
-          "from": "broccoli-asset-rewrite@>=1.1.0 <2.0.0",
+          "from": "https://registry.npmjs.org/broccoli-asset-rewrite/-/broccoli-asset-rewrite-1.1.0.tgz",
           "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/broccoli-asset-rewrite/-/broccoli-asset-rewrite-1.1.0.tgz"
```

Coming from a Ruby world with Bundler, I don't understand the logic behind this. Why should npm-shrinkwrap change between a URL and a name every time I run it? This makes `npm-shrinkwrap.json` impracticable for version control, in my opinion.

How can I make `npm-shrinkwrap` consistent and only use URLs or names?

Answer (score 1):

It's more about how you install package with npm and when. You can read explanation [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9550)